# How to open dialog and change url withour reload whole page in Nuxtjs

Tags: url, routes, vuejs2, parameters, nuxt.js

My project using Nuxtjs2 to clone Trello. When I clicked the task, which opened the dialog while simultaneously changing the URL, but it caused the page to reload.
Example Url: `/project/1` when I clicked, it was pushed additionally parameter "task-1". Then url updated: `/project/1/task-1`

```js
openDialog() {
  const taskId = this.card.id
  const projectId = this.card.project_id
  this.showDialog = true
  this.$router.push({
    path: `/project/${projectId}/${taskId}`,
  })
},
```

`/project/${projectId}` is the previous path url. I dont want use query("?") or hash ("#")

Comment: hash("#") sorry

Comment: in your project, do you have a route for the taskId ? like in `/pages/_pid` ? (Note: you can edit your question to fix typos and add more details)

Comment: @Jimmar I dont have the taskId route. In trello, it open task detail and change url without reload. I wonder how